# Is there any event present in hibernate which listens select / read operation?

Tags: java, hibernate, interceptor

I want to perform some operation whenever any select operation is performed on database using hibernate (HQL/ Criteria).

Is there any way apart from / or in hibernate interceptor or events for this.

I can not use onLoad() / instantiate() method of hibernate interceptor.(EmptyInterceptor).

Comment: Isn't your program the only thing that reds/writes to the DB?

Comment: I need to perform further checks on data that comes out of select

Comment: Why? Is your app not the only app that uses that database?